# How to make this work? RewriteCond %{ENV:UNIQUE_ID} !%{QUERY_STRING}

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

/foo/.htaccess does an internal redirect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/?%{ENV:UNIQUE_ID}
```

/bar/.htaccess needs to recognise that the request was NOT internal, the issue is that I cannot figure out how to make the comparision work

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:UNIQUE_ID} !%{QUERY_STRING}
```

even a

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %{QUERY_STRING}
```

won't match, I suppose there is a syntax issue in the right-hand of the expression, escaping % doesn't help.

I tested that the above both variable have the same value on an internal redirect as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/%{QUERY_STRING}/%{ENV:UNIQUE_ID}
```

would show it.

The server is Apache/2.2.3

Thanks,
Laurian

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sadly you cannot compare two variables directly with mod_rewrite. (Or at least I don’t know how to do this either.)

But there is a workaround for this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:UNIQUE_ID}:%{QUERY_STRING} !^(.+):\1$
```

I chose the `:` as separator but you can use any other separator if you want to. And if you can specify the structure of `UNIQUE_ID` values, you should do that.

Comment: This is SO useful! I didn't realise that you could combine multiple environmental values like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the referrer wasn't the same domain you are on, such as the first time a person visits but didn't use a link within your own website, you could check the HTTP_REFERRER. Same technique is used to prevent hotlinking to images.